# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I am getting  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in my dynamic web application even though I have set build path correctly in `Eclipse` for `mysql connector`. I am pretty sure that I have set built path correctly. I doubled checked that. 
I ran through so many same kind of questions in stackoverflow. All of them suggest to set build path in `Eclipse`.
My question is, are there any other ways that can generate  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error? If so , how to solve that?
Thank you!

Comment: How is your web application being deployed?  Is it a war file?  If so, is the mysql-connector jar in the war?

Comment: `set built path correctly` means you have the `mysql-connector-java.jar` in it? Do you run it in eclipse?

Comment: i guess you deploy on an application server, dont you? If you do, you might have to add the jdbc driver jar to your application server lib folder.

Comment: What eclipse builds into your war, and what classpath your web application uses, these are different things! First you had to check if your war contains the mysql connector. If yes, you had to check the filesystem in your tomcat server, if there is on its place.

Comment: @jens I have put `mysql-connector-java.jar` file in a folder called `libs` and I correctly set build path

Comment: @user3892439 And you run it in eclipse or on a web-/appserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your `mysql-connector-java.jar` file inside `Web-INF` folder ->  `lib` and add it in classpath and then export your WAR and deploy.

This Documentation - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

says

> Therefore, from the perspective of a web application, class or resource loading looks in the following repositories, in this order:
>
> - Bootstrap classes of your JVM
> - `/WEB-INF/classes` of your web application
> - `/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` of your web application  `<----------`
> - System class loader classes (described above)
> - Common class loader classes (described above)

Comment: putting `mysql-connector-java.jar`in `web-INF` worked ! thanks..But I have developped applications without putting that jar file outside that folder, in a seperate folder inside the project folder. What happened this time?

Comment: Those applications may not be web applications on tomcat..